# postgres will not allow less to chop long lines

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql, less-unix

Every time I get a big query, I try to type -S in my pager (less), and while I see the prompts for "chop long lines" and "fold long lines", nothing happens when I hit enter.

Also: this option should be on by default based on my config:

```
postgres=> \pset pager on
Pager is used for long output.
postgres=> \q
[jacob@dev_server ~]$ grep PAGER ~/.bash_profile 
export PAGER="less -S" psql
```

What else should I do to debug this?

Comment: If you really start up `psql` at the end of your `.bash_profile` and never exit it, that would be worth explicitly mentioning.  The syntax of the `export` is weird in any event.  Does it work if you take out the `psql` and/or move it to the next line?

Comment: No it doesn't work either way, with or without psql in the line and with or without the line itself. I think the psql setting via \pset pager on is sufficient...but something is wrong with the less environment only in the postgres context. I can use less -S in all other contexts.

Comment: So if you quit `psql` do you see `less -S` if you `echo "$PAGER"`?

Comment: yes: [jacob@dev_server]$ echo "$PAGER"
less -S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following in my environment settings and it's always worked for me.

```
PAGER="less"
LESS="-S"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set defaults for less(1) using the `${LESS}` environment variable.

Note that you can set environment settings from your `~/.psqlrc` using `\setenv`. This is useful if, for instance, you want a different value for `${LESS}` inside psql than you do at the shell prompt.

For example, you could add these lines to your `~/.psqlrc`:

```
\setenv LESS '-nRSQ -z-2 -j2'
\setenv PAGER less
```